# This site can’t be reached $pdf = new \Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf("C:\Users\folders\Desktop\folder\SOP.pdf");

Tags: pdf, yii2, spatie-ssh

Im working on Yii2 project which convert pdf to image using Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf plugin. However, when I try to use the plugin it cannot load the page it seems like connection lost but only on the page where the code is put.

```
In this code I only wanted to get only the number of pages.
```

> ```
> $pdf = new \Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf("C:\Users\userFolder\Desktop\folder\SOP.pdf");
> $pdf->getNumberOfPages();
> ```

[image: Here is my error]

[image]

Comment: Can you show all the code?  You could be missing an include or something like that.

Comment: That all my include plugin

Comment: I also install gostscrip and added it to environment variable but still same error